# RNGCryptoServiceProvider: generate random numbers in the range [0, randomMax)

Tags: c#, random

I wrote the following code to generate random numbers in the [0, int.MaxValue) range, but I wasn't sure how to restrict the range to [0, randomMax) while maintaining an even distribution:

```
private static int GetNextInt32(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider random)
{
  var buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
  random.GetBytes(buffer);
  return Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=775. See the section titled "Creating a System.Random Replacement."

Note, however, that using the modulus operator might not be the best way to ensure a good distribution. A possibly better way would be `(int)(NextDouble() * (MaxValue - 1));`

Your code has a latent bug. If `buffer` contains the hex values `00 00 00 80`, which is `int.MinValue`, `Math.Abs` will throw an exception.

Note that calling `GetBytes` on the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is very slow compared to calling `Random.Next`. You're better off calling `GetBytes` to fill a larger buffer, and then dribble the random numbers from it. My example shows how that's done.

Comment: Jim, `Next() % maxValue` is biased; as a simple example if `Next()` returns 0, 1, 2 or 3 evenly distributed, `Next() % 3` will return 0 twice as frequently as 1 or 2.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, I did mention that using the modulus operator could be a problem. Thanks for the concrete example.

Comment: Apologies, I hadn't seen your caveat there.

Answer (score 3):

There's a description of a suitable algorithm in the [Java `nextInt` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

The algorithm repeatedly rejects any values that will cause an uneven distribution and tries again. This means, theoretically, that in the worst-case scenario it could loop forever. In reality it will be pretty quick.

Here's a (completely untested) C# translation:

```
public static int GetNextInt32(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng, int maxValue)
{
    if (maxValue < 1)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxValue", maxValue, "Value must be positive.");

    var buffer = new byte[4];
    int bits, val;

    if ((maxValue & -maxValue) == maxValue)  // is maxValue an exact power of 2
    {
        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        bits = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        return bits & (maxValue - 1);
    }

    do
    {
        rng.GetBytes(buffer);
        bits = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        val = bits % maxValue;
    } while (bits - val + (maxValue - 1) < 0);

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An MSDN magazine article shows you how to create a `Random` that uses the cryptographic RNG:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163367.aspx

(The article is no longer directly accessible.  It was from the September 2007 issue, the title was "Tales from the CryptoRandom".  You'll have to download the archived issue.  It's .chm so you'll have to unblock it as being from the internet, before you can read it.  You could also use the internet archive.)

Comment: Right now, the link above redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/september/net-matters-tales-from-the-cryptorandom which is the correct article.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need much speed, maybe you can try this:

```
    private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider _RNG = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();  

    private static int GetNextRnd (int min, int max)
    {
        byte[] rndBytes = new byte[4];
        _RNG.GetBytes(rndBytes);
        int rand = BitConverter.ToInt32(rndBytes, 0); 
        const Decimal OldRange = (Decimal)int.MaxValue - (Decimal)int.MinValue;
        Decimal NewRange = max - min;
        Decimal NewValue = ((Decimal)rand - (Decimal)int.MinValue) / OldRange * NewRange + (Decimal)min;
        return (int)NewValue;
    }
```

This will scale the full-range `int` number to your range of values, mantaining the distribution.

I know it's an old post, but I've run to a similar problem and this soultion worked for me.